# php cake inflection.php - why is "cookie" in list of uninflected words?

Tags: cakephp

Simple question - in the CAKE php framework - in inflection.php (class inflection)

why is "cookie" in the list of  terms NOT to apply pluralization to?

```
uninflected' => array('.*[nrlm]ese', '.*deer', '.*fish', '.*measles', '.*ois', '.*pox', '.*sheep', 'people', 'cookie')
```

I get all of the rest but 'cookie' doesn't make sense. e.g. plural is cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that it is in that list by mistake. The cookie/cookies part can also be found where it actually belongs: in the irregular words section.

But the inflection of this word works nevertheless.
You can pluralize and singulare Cookie/Cookies just fine (I confirmed it using the current 2.3 head).

I made a PR (you could have done the same, of course) to clear this up: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/1048

Comment: Aha, in the bug you filed, they mentioned that the test case for cookie/cookies still behaves as expected. I looked into it further and found that there is a rule in the plurals array that would fire for cookie/cookies, thus, the logic would stop before reaching the uninflected array logic, thus, it never fires.

Comment: Thanks also for taking the step of filing a ticket (you are right I should have done so). Thanks again.